# SASS/Compass better organizing

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

everyone.
I start to learn how to use SASS and Compass and whant to ask advice in better organizing this snippet of code

```
.main-link.first-item {
  @include background(image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat -27px -39px,
                      linear-gradient(#4b4e58, #3f424a));

  &:hover {
    @include background(image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat -27px -1px,
                        linear-gradient(#4b4e58, #3f424a));
  }
```

How can I use linear gradient without repeting, but only changing position of image?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but is it possible to save the values in variables and use them instead of "hard coded" pixel values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust the background position of the first image.

```
&:hover {
    background-position: -27px -1px, 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @cimmanon's answer.

Although if you want to use the same thing over and over again on different elements in different stylesheets I would propose to create a mixin and put it into a separate sass file. Than you can import that into the files where you need it:

```
# mixin.css.scss
@mixin custom-background($bg-sprite, $position-vertical, $position-horizontal) {
  @include background(image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat $position-vertical $position-horizontal,
                        linear-gradient(#4b4e58, #3f424a));
}

# some.css.scss
@import "mixin.css.scss"

.main-link.first-item {
    @include custom-background($bg-sprite, -27px, -39px);
  &:hover {
    @include custom-background($bg-sprite, -27px, -1px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, understand everithing.

Comment: This technically still repeats the code.  Only difference is that *you* aren't the one duplicating it, Sass is.  The code duplication still exists in the generated CSS and is entirely unnecessary.